# Multi file backbone.js application doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a view in a .js file apart the 'index.html' file which looks like this :

```
window.App = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#article'),

        initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
            console.log('binding');
            console.log($('#article'));
            this.render();
        },

        render: function() {
            console.log('rendering');
            this.$el.html("rendered");
            return this;
        }
    });
```

I am allocating this view in 'index.html' using JQuery's ready function :

```
<div id="article">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        console.log($('#article'));
        new window.App();
    });
</script>
```

As you may guess, "rendered" doesn't appear on the DOM. The problem is that when i pack everything together (the view and the allocation in the  tag), it works.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What does `console.log(window.App)` have to say if you put it in your `$(function() {...})`?

Comment: `function (){a.apply(this,arguments)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that this:

```
window.App = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#article'),
```

happens before this HTML:

```
<div id="article">
</div>
```

is seen by the browser. That would leave `$('#article')` empty and your `render` method wouldn't have access to anything in the DOM. Open your console and run this demo and you'll see what you're seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7sGcZ/

The easiest solution is to use the selector as `el`:

```
window.App = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#article',
```

and let Backbone turn it into a DOM element on its own. That way, `$('#article')` will find something when Backbone needs to create the view's [`$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el).

Demo (that works): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Vd6jP/